# codepush react native new package

Tags: react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

I tried react native code push and it works flawlessly. Let's say I modify the text in my buttons to say something else, then with a single command, the update is sent to the users.

Now, lets say I am using a new npm library which requires some native code. Say react-native-image-picker (https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker). Can code push handles this? I want the image picker functionality to be updated too in my users app. Thank you.

Comment: Code Push cannot update native code, only changes made to JavaScript, CSS, Images. You will need to make a new release through the App Store or Google Play when you update native code.

Answer (score 1):

No - CodePush can only update JavaScript code and images.

CodePush does not update native code at all so any changes to native code require a full app build and deploy via the relevant app store or app distribution tool (e.g. HockeyApp).

Note: There are some limitations around images - full details [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push#supported-components).